# React: How to pass html as prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create a component that I'll use as 
`<Component htmldata=? />` in a mdx file.

That component will be like that: `...etc render{return{ <div> {this.props.htmldata} </div>}}`. To what must I assign the `htmldata` property to return some HTML inside the div. My aim is to use the same component easily in the mdx file multiple times with different `htmldata` without having to create another component.

Edit: i recommend using a function that returns html and is binded and passed as a prop. example:

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {

  linkfunction: this.props.link.bind(this)
}
```

}
this function is passed as a prop like that:

```
<LiveCode title="MyhtmlComponent" link={function(){return <p>the html i pass </p> ;}} />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want put JSX(html) throught props, usually is better use props.childern

[React js - documentation (about props childern)](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html)

or you can use dangerouslySetInnerHTML

[Reactjs - dangerouslysetinnerhtml](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` but that is not recommended

Read more here

https://zhenyong.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html